# JavaScript and Ajax "@"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to do a HTTP-Request to the server. But I need an authentication for it. Used the one below, but now my username is an email and it's not working (get an undefined). Has someone an idea what is wrong with the "@" in JS? How can I encode it?

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: urlString,
     async: false,
     beforeSend: function(x) {
         },
     dataType: "json",
     username: "email@email.com",
     password: "password",
     success: function(data){
     returnData = data;
     }
});
```

Comment: What is the server returning to you? Can you inspect in Firebug and tell us what it thinks is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the username as "email%40email.com"?

Comment: @user1113426 and ocanal Check the docs, they both exist.

Comment: Is the URL a script that expects query string arguments (e.g., $_GET['username']), or are you trying to pass HTTP credentials?  The username/password attributes are for http://username:password@www.example.com, for accessing a page protected by the web server itself (by .htaccess in Apache, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the posted answers seem to be implying that the `data` option with a parameter named `username` is equivalent to the `username` option.  I don't believe this to be true, but do not have a test environment at the moment to find out.

I think `username` and `password` are similar to the way you pass a username and password in a URL (`username:password@host`) which was often used for browser access of ftp sites, etc.  It is actually a username and password, not just request parameters.

If my assumptions are correct, I believe all you will need to do is this:

`email%40email.com`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `username` and `password` in inside a data object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: urlString,
  async: false,
  beforeSend: function(x) {
  },
  dataType: "json",
  data: {username: "email@email.com", password: "password"},
  success: function(data){
    returnData = data;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: urlString,
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  data: {     
    username: "email@email.com",
    password: "password",
  }
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  console.log("done. msg:" + msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Or passing parameters with a string:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: urlString,
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  data: "username=email@email.com&password=password"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  console.log("done. msg:" + msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: **"username: String, A username to be used in response to an HTTP access authentication request."**  Are you sure passing a request parameter named "username" is going to do the same thing?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Excuse me, can you please explain more?

Comment: He is attempting to use the `username` option of `ajax`.  What I pasted is the description of this option.  Your solution is to pass it in the `data` option, which I do not believe to be equivalent.  I was wondering if you knew something I didn't and that the two were equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Brandon's answer is the better way to code this, but if you are specifically looking for a way to encode the email address in the url, use javascript's native encodeURIComponent():

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: urlString,
     async: false,
     beforeSend: function(x) {
         },
     dataType: "json",
     username: encodeURIComponent("email@email.com"),
     password: "password",
     success: function(data){
     returnData = data;
     }
});
```